# Azure App Service 500 error Timeout Http Post

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

Have web application using angular 4.x and Web Api 2.0 which is deployed in Azure App Services. All of sudden the application started throwing 500 error for the first time when save the form after a while (here the request did not reaches the controller). Angular make the HTTP Post to Controller to save the data to DB.

> 500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within
>   the specified time.

I have tried different options in configuration file but no luck.

```
   <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
          <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
        </modules>
<handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"  resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

Able to see the Http 500/server error count in Azure Portal but not able to get any details.

Here is screen shot the error. **Before Calling Controller** is printed from angular before http post to Web api controller. As I mentioned, the issue happening first time and working fine later. Application is configured to use AAD authentication

[image]

Comment: Its difficult to help as you don't even know what the error was. I think you should add error logs to your webapi in order to help with your debugging. 

I presuming that you are using WebApi 2.0 C#
Eg. Trace / Elmah or other methods in your catch block. 

Also, may be you should run the webapi locally and have your angular app to point to that and see if you can see anything in the output screen of Visual studio.

Comment: The error not happening in local and enabled logging in controller method but the call not getting transferred to controller from angular when the user getting 500 error(timed out) (logging not recorded) when error happens. BTW our application configured to use the AAD authentication

Comment: In this case, I think the webApi simply rejected the connection. Are you able to see anything in the browser console like (chrome developer tool)?

Comment: updated the error screen shot to question. I got the below message from Network tab of Chrome developer tool 
500 - The request timed out. The web server failed to respond within the specified time